# Can't read table data in as400 error SQL0204

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm trying to find data in an AS400 either through Excel with ODBC or through the free DBeaver software. My problem is that of many tables I can read the name and properties but I can't read the data because I get the error "SQL0204 * FIRST in * N" etc.

For example I can read the DTLEG00F table but not the CEGENDS table.

Why?

[image: table DTLEG00F]

[image: table CEGENDS]

[image: Properties of CEGENDS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL0204 actually means table not found. In addition to above recommendation, please try:

1. find library where this table exists;
2. find out jobd associated with your login ID ;
3. find out if library is part of jobd; also
4. qualify it with library, e.g
   select * from Lib/tablename

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that no data member is in the table...

Either, there really isn't a data member, or perhaps the table is a Distributed Data Management (DDM) table.

From a 5250 command line, try the Display File Description (DSPFD) command.

You want to look at two sections, File description Header
[image]

and on the second page of Data Base File Attributes, number of members
[image]

Lastly, at the very bottom, there's a list of members
[image]